# Change background colour of a DataGrid column based on attached property

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, attached-properties

I am trying to style a `DataGrid` such that if a column has an attached property to indicate if it is highlighted. So those cells in a column where  `Highlighted = true` would have a different colour to those columns with `Highlighted = false`.

My attached property looks like:

```
public static class Highlighted
{
    public static bool GetIsHighlighted(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsHighlightedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsHighlighted(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsHighlightedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighlightedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsHighlighted", typeof(bool), typeof(Highlighted), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

And the `DataGridCell` style looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="WeldOfficeDataGridCell" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="0.5"
                        Background="FloralWhite" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" 
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Margin="15,5,5,5" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="attachedProperties:Highlighted.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor2}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I am setting the property in the `DataGrid` like:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="27,17,0,0"
              Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FilterableBaseMaterials}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              HeadersVisibility="Column"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              Background="{x:Null}">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Specification" IsReadOnly="True" attachedProperties:Highlighted.IsHighlighted="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Specification}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            ...
```

But after several frustrating hours i cannot figure out how to get this to work, my `Style.Trigger` for the attached property is wrong as it never triggers the change in colour, i guess because i have the property attached to the column and not the `DataGridCell` but i cannot figure out how to get this to work, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the `IsHighlighted` attached property of the *column*. This is not the same thing as setting it on the *cell*.

You should set it on the cell that eventually gets created by the column. The only way you can do this in pure XAML is to define a `CellStyle` for the column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Specification" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource WeldOfficeDataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="attachedProperties:Highlighted.IsHighlighted" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Specification}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```